# How to add new column to table generated by FixedTable jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am new to the jQuery FixedTable plugin.

I want to add a new row to an existing table.

I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<table id="tbl" border="1"></table>
```

Jquery

```
$('#tbl').append( '<tr><td>Nitin</td></tr>' );
$('#tbl').append( '<tr><td>Akk</td></tr>' );
```

Comment: I tried such type of things. But this jquery.fixable.js plugin create internally many 2 tables FixedColumn and FixedContainer. So after table initialization is completed, we are not able to append any new row..so i am asking about how to refresh that table again